# $\bar{\partial}$ operator of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, coordinate-systems, chain-rule

Let $\bar{\partial}$ be the Cauchy–Riemann operator that is for $z=x+i y$,
$$\bar{\partial} = \frac{1}{2i}\left( i\partial_x - \partial_y\right).$$
Now assume that $z=u+ve^{ia}$, where $u$ and $v$ are **real** variables, $a\in (0,1)$ a **real** constant, and we want to calculate $\bar{\partial} f(z)$ in terms of $\partial_u$ and $\partial_v$.

My question is that the following claim correct?
$$\bar{\partial} f(z)=\frac{1}{2 i \sin a} \left( e^{i a} \partial_u f-\partial_v f\right).$$
In my attempt, I used the chain rule. I found the same first term on r.h.s, but I got a different term for the second.

**Edit:**
Here is my calculation:

Write $z=u+ve^{ia}=(u+v\cos a)+i (v\sin a)=u'+iv'$. Then
$$\bar{\partial} f(z)=\frac{1}{2 i} \left(i \partial_{u'} f-\partial_{v'} f\right).$$
By the chain rule, we have $\partial_{u'} f=\partial_{u} f + \frac{1}{\cos a} \partial_{v} f$ and $\partial_{v'} f=-\cot a \;\partial_{u} f + \frac{1}{\sin a} \partial_{v} f$. When replacing we get
$$\bar{\partial} f(z)=\frac{1}{2 i \sin a} \left( e^{i a} \partial_u f- (i \tan a -1)\partial_v f\right).$$

Comment: Yes, the claim is correct. I think you should write your calculation so we can point out what went wrong.

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Comment: I removed the "Cauchy-Riemann equations" tag and replaced it with "coordinate systems" tag, since I think it is more appropiate for the central point of the question.

Comment: Suggested title: "$\bar\partial$ operator of a function under change of coordinates" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea seems to be allright, but I think you made some mistake using the chain rule (I'm still not sure what the error was).

Remember the chain rule says

$$\begin{aligned}
\partial_x&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\partial_u+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\partial_v \\
\partial_y&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\partial_u+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\partial_v.
\end{aligned}$$
(There's no need to introduce $u'$ and $v'$, since these are the usual $x$ and $y$.)

The partial derivatives that appear in these equations tell you that you need $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.
Solving from your equation
$$x+iy=(u+v\cos a)+i(v\sin a),$$
you get
$$\begin{aligned}
u&=x-y\cot a \\
v&=y/\sin a.
\end{aligned}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: My mistake was in $\partial_x v$, which is $0$, when I calculate it, I replaced $y$ from the equation of $u$ to get dependence with $x$. Thanks again.